# Find eigenvectors of a simple matrix over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the field $\mathbb{F}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is prime ($a$ is a generator of this field). I want to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ over the field. I find that there is a unique eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. Now I want to compute the corresponding eigenvectors vectors. I compute $M-\lambda I$ and I get $$M=\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ So the eigenvectors $v$ should satisfy $av_2=0$ and there is no constraints on $v_1$. What I want to show is that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$ is the whole space $\mathbb{F}_p\times\mathbb{F}_p$. I think it is clear because there is only one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ but I want to see this in the calculations. But $av_2=0$ doesn't mean we can take $v_2$ arbitrary no?

Comment: But the eigenspace is **not** the whole space; it is one-dimensional.

Comment: Weird. Why do you label $\mathbb F_p$ as $\mathbb F_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a = 0$, then we can take $v_2$ to be arbitrary since $v_2a$ will be zero no matter what $v_2$ is, and the eigenspace is two-dimensional.

If $a\neq 0$, then we must have $v_2 = 0$ since that's the only way to make $av_2 = 0$, and thus the eigenspace is one-dimensional, as it is the span of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Note that everything here is true no matter what field we're actually working over. In fact, a lot of linear algebra is base-field agnostic (i.e. works exactly the same over any field).